# How do you remove the explicit permissions on every item in a TFS project?

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS environment which has lots of different folders and branches and a lot of the branches have explicit permissions.

How do I reset these on mass to inherit so I can configure the permissions properly without having to go into each branch individually?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm looking to something that resets the permissions on mass as we have a lot of branches and I don't want to have to go into each branch individually

Comment: Hi Inverted Llama Thanks for getting back to me. For now **Clear explicit permissions** only works for the selected branch, which will not either inherit to or effect  child branches. `looking to something that resets the permissions on mass as we have a lot of branches` This is not supported, sorry for any inconvenience. You could submit a user voice here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea Our PM will kindly review any features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update:***

For now **Clear explicit permissions only works for the selected branch** , which will not either inherit to or effect any child branches.

`looking to something that resets the permissions on mass as we have a lot of branches`

This is not supported, sorry for any inconvenience. You could submit a user voice here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea Our PM will kindly review any feature requests.

---

You could first **turn on your inheritance** and **clear explicit** with single click for each branch which have explicit permissions.

[image]
[image]

After this, Contributors Group in other branches will totally inherit the permissions set by root path of your repo/workspace.  For example, if root path are Allow, your branches should be Allow(inherited), if it's Deny, your branches should be Deny(inherited).

If a permission isn't directly allowed or denied for a user, then it may be inherited in two ways.

- Users inherit permissions from the groups to which they belong. When
  a permission is allowed for a user directly or through membership in
  a group that has that permission, and it is denied, either directly
  or through group membership, the permission is denied.

  Members of **Project Collection Administrators** or **Team Foundation
  Administrators** retain any allowed permissions, even if they belong to
  other groups that deny those permissions.
- Object-level permissions that are assigned for nodes of a hierarchy -
  areas, iterations, version control folders, work item query folders -
  are inherited down the hierarchy. That is, a user's permissions that
  are set at area-1 are inherited by area-1/sub-area-1, if the same
  permission is not explicitly allowed or denied for area-1/sub-area-1.
  If a permission is set explicitly for an object, like
  area-1/sub-area-1, then the parent node is not inherited, regardless
  of whether it is denied or allowed. If it's not set, then the
  permissions for that node are inherited from the closest ancestor
  that has the permission explicitly set.

More details please take a look at our official tutorial here: [Inheritance and security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops#inheritance-and-security-groups)